# Odd behaviour with displaying length of numbers in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I can't quite get my head around this issue, it seems like something is conflicting somewhere, however I have the following JQuery loaded in to my website to display the values of any `<li>` items in which are selected (on click)

```
<script>
var $x = jQuery.noConflict();
$x(function() { 
  const $xshowList = $x("#shownumbers");
  $x("ul").on("click", function(e) {  
    $x(e.target).toggleClass("selected"); 
    $xshowList.text($x(".selected", this).map(function() {  
        return $x(this).attr("data-seat-number")
      }).get() // the array
      .join(", ") 
    );
  })
})
</script>
```

The list structure I have setup is powered by a WordPress plugin which displays a table on my website, with clickable `<li>` list items (Each list item has a number value ranging from 1 to 50)

Finally, I have a `div` container (with the ID "shownumbers") which is displaying the list of numbers which are selected based on the whichever `<li>` tags have been clicked by the user.

E.g. 1, 3, 5, 24, 30

Here's the odd behaviour part:

When the page loads, no numbers are displayed within the "shownumbers" div (Which is working accordingly) - However, when I click a number e.g. 14, the number 14 isn't appearing, but if I click another number e.g. 28, then the number 14 shows. If I click another number, the number clicked won't display, until I click yet another number at random (Between the list of numbers displaying on my page)

It's almost like, something is conflicting somewhere which is preventing the initial selected number from appearing straight away until another number is pressed.

The pattern is - Click a number, the initial number doesn't display until another number is clicked. (This pattern goes for each number selected thereafter)

Is there any typical suggestions with what could normally cause something like this? I can share further code with you, but it is a third-party plugin I am using for producing the `<li>` list on my page, as apart of an seat booking (events) plugin.

Ideally the user should be able to select their seat numbers and the numbers they've should selected should display within the `"shownumbers"` div.

Thanks!

Comment: Usual cause is that the collecting of values occurs before the selection criteria changes - typically with checkboxes where click occurs before change event - so checkbox is not yet ticked.  Can you provide some HTML to provide a snippet that demonstrates the issue? See [mcve].  In your case it might be that toggleClass appears after the .text lines

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you've *provided* works fine with some extrapolated HTML:  https://jsfiddle.net/jvp2utwx/ without seeing the issue *in action*, there's not much we can do except guess.